# App crashes on CGContext.drawPDFPage with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, cgcontext

My app is randomly crashing on **CGContext.drawPDFPage** without a way to reproduce the bug consistently. It happens mostly on iPads. The code looks something like this:

```
override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {

  UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)
  ctx.saveGState()

  defer {
    ctx.restoreGState()
    UIGraphicsPopContext()
  }

  ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
  ctx.fill(viewBounds)

  ctx.translateBy(x: 0, y: viewBounds.height)
  ctx.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
  ctx.scaleBy(x: pdfScale, y: pdfScale)

  ctx.interpolationQuality = .high
  ctx.setRenderingIntent(.defaultIntent)

  ctx.beginPDFPage(nil)
  ctx.drawPDFPage(pdfPage) // This is where the crash happens
  ctx.endPDFPage()
}
```

The stack trace ends in `CGPDFObjectGetReference` and looks like this:

[image: Stack]

The error is: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. If you see anything that could be causing this crash would help me a lot!

Comment: Do you have an error in console when this happens? Could it be a memory issue? Since you draw "larger images", it could be the reasons why it crashes on iPad, and not on iPhones. And `ctx.drawPDFPage(pdfPage)`, where is defined `pdfPage`?

Comment: @Larme the error is a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" with no more information. This is why it's been so hard to debug. Memory doesn't seem to be high enough to cause a crash... pdfPage is defined in the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## iOS 12

Anyone, who reached the similar crash, the case was in the cache layer which by index were requested `CGPDFDocument` and `CGPDFPage` in specific cases.

Solution is to request PDF from persistent storage on demand.

## iOS 13

Starting from iOS 13 – we don't see any bugs related to this, thus probably Apple resolved the bug with restoring the context from values of `CGPDFDocument` and `CGPDFPage` types.